# How can I update a column (multiple rows) in a table with the lower value between 2 column in 2 tables?

Tags: sql, select, multiple-tables

I need to compare the comision of the seller and the comision of the product and put the lower value in the comision column in details.

```
table 1: details 

doc  comision seller product
1       0      001     0101
1       0      001     0315
1       0      001     0425
2       0      001     0389
2       0      001     0315

table 2: products
code  description   comision
0101  product 1        5
0315  product 2        7
0425  product 3        3
0389  product 4        8
.
.
.

table 3: sellers
code  name         comision
001   seller 1        6
002   seller 2        3
.
.
.
```

I did this:

```
declare @comisionVendedor float,@comisionProducto float, @comision float,@prod='0101'
set @comisionVendedor=0
set @comisionProducto=0
select @comisionVendedor=comision from vendedor join details on seller.CODe=details.seller where details.doc=1 and prod=@prod
select @comisionProducto=products.COMISION from products join details on products.CODe=details.PRODuct where details.doc=1 and prod=@prod
if @comisionVendedor>@comisionProducto begin set @comision=@comisionProducto end
else begin set @comision=@comisionVendedor end

update details set comision=@comision where details.doc=1 and product=@prod
```

It works fine but with only one product.  How can I replace the comision column of the 3 rows with the doc number of 1?

Comment: all of them have different products.so your code works as expected.try removing the hardcoding of @prod and use a JOIN instead

Answer (score -1):

You could use the [printf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) command